# Merging only one nested property in reducer state

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have the following state:

```
 new Map({
    data: new Map({
        all: null,
        recent: null
    }),
    filters: new Map({
        pagination: new Map({
            currentPage: 1
        }),
        sortBy: new Map({
            key: 'id',
            order: 'desc'
        })
    }),
    various: new Map()
}
```

And I want to change only `currentPage` property, leaving `sortBy` alone, like this:

```
case PAGINATE:
    return state.merge({
        filters: new Map({
            pagination: new Map({
                currentPage: action.response
            })
        })
    })
```

But instead, the `sortBy` is erased from `filters`, I have to do something like this to make it work properly:

```
case PAGINATE:
    return state.merge({
        filters: new Map({
            pagination: new Map({
                currentPage: action.response
            }),
            sortBy: new Map({
                key: state.getIn(['filters', 'sortBy', 'key']),
                order: state.getIn(['filters', 'sortBy', 'order'])
            })
        })
    })
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can like this

```
return state.merge({
    filters: state.get('filters').merge({
         pagination: new Map({
             currentPage: action.response
         })
    })
})
```

Read more from [here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use `mergeIn`, which is a combination of `updateIn` and `merge`, returning a new Map, but performing the merge at a point arrived at by following the keyPath.

So that your code will look like this:

```
case PAGINATE:
  return state.mergeIn(['filters', 'pagination'], {
    currentPage: action.response
  })
```

Read more about `mergeIn` from [here](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mergeIn).